# Create specific lines using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, global-scene

I want to find the center of a closed oval, but it can't be done with the tools, so I thought that it is possible to connect the extreme points of this oval and where the intersection of these lines will be and there will be a center, how can this be done?

[image]

I tried to find the center with the meancenter tool, but it gives strange results, clearly not where the center is. I have an oval that is in the photo, but it doesn't have an attribute table, and there is also a point layer that contains 360 values.

I created the lines, but they are not straight and arc-shaped, how can I fix it?
[image]

[image]

I couldn't find the right center, I don't understand how I can find it

Comment: You have a tag for a Global Scene but is that what you are using or just a Map?  Do you have your oval as a polygon?  If so, have you tried finding its centroid?

Comment: I tried to find the center with the meancenter tool, but it gives strange results, clearly not where the center is

Comment: I have an oval that is in the photo, but it doesn't have an attribute table, and there is also a point layer that contains 360 values.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculating area in ArcGIS Pro Global Scene](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/387719/calculating-area-in-arcgis-pro-global-scene)